# Normalisation / 3rd Normal Form In Tables?

Tags: mysql, normalization, database-normalization

I'm creating a small news website and someone suggested that I look at normalisation, which I did and although I understand it I don't quite know if it's relevant to ALL tables in a database. For instance, I have this "Articles" table consisting of:

```
ID                      -   10001
Featured                -   0 or 1
Category                -   Category Name
Title                   -   Title For The Article
Article                 -   This is the article.....
Photo Description       -   Photo to go with blog 10001
Photo Name              -   John Smith
Photo Link              -   www.johnsmith.com
Author                  -   myname@gmail.com
Keywords                -   keyword, keyword, keyword, ...
Added                   -   2014-07-27 10:41
Views                   -   600
```

Is there anything wrong with leaving this table as it is or does it need to be converted to 3rd normal form?

EDIT:

What if I had:

```
**Authors**

ID
email
name
avatar
bio
website_link
facebook_link
twitter_link

**Articles**

ID                      -   10001
Featured                -   0 or 1
Title                   -   Title For The Article
Article                 -   This is the article.....
Photo                   -   10001.jpg
Photo Description       -   Acts as alt tag
Photo Name              -   Crediting photographer
Photo Link              -   Link to credited photographer
Author                  -   Author ID
Added                   -   2014-07-27 10:41
Views                   -   600

**categories**

ID
category

**article_categories**

ID
article_id
category_id
```

I'm still finding it hard to grasp the reasons why having so many tables is such a great thing though as now there are lots of joins that need to be made. Why isn't it easier to use php to say

`select * from articles where category == $category`

or

`select * from articles where featured == 0`

or

`select * from articles where author == $author_id`, etc, etc

Comment: It needs to be improved.

Comment: Comma-separated values are almost always a mistake if you need to match them.

Comment: Ok @juergend, so how exactly do I improve it? I mean all of the columns are relevant to the article - Wouldn't splitting the data into more tables complicate things?

Comment: No, splitting the data will make certain operations possible. E.g. if you want to find all the articles containing keywords `a` and `b`, then there is no way (in your current schema) to create indices that will prevent a full table scan of all your articles.

Comment: how many keywords will be there for one news?

Comment: @timus2001 I guess it will be up to the author. The keywords is really used for both finding a key word where I was going to use PHP `LIKE` and also for the meta keywords tag

Comment: what would you do if you need match 2 news according to similar tags or need to list out mostly used tag for some news

Comment: @timus2001 Well using `%LIKE%` would get all the articles with a given keyword. I'm site that there is a way of filtering out the most used with a similar method right?

Comment: @user3177012 I would encourage you to try writing a query to get the most frequently used tags - it may not be as easy as you think. Compare that to a simple `group by` query that you would use if the keywords had their own table.  ps: `like` queries are fine, but very slow.

Comment: Thanks @thebjorn, I'm sure that you're right. I'll try to look into a better way of doing it

Answer (score 4):

**Make seperate table for news,category,photo,authors and keywords**

**News**

```
ID                      -   10001
Featured                -   0 or 1
category_id             -   //belongs to category table
Title                   -   Title For The Article
Article                 -   This is the article.....
Added                   -   2014-07-27 10:41
Views                   -   600
```

**categories**

```
ID
name
```

**Photos**

```
ID
Photo Description       -   Photo to go with blog 10001
Photo Name              -   John Smith
Photo Link              -   www.johnsmith.com
```

**Authors**

```
ID
Author                  -   myname@gmail.com
```

**keywords**

```
ID                      -   10001
Keywords                -   keyword
```

One news may have multiple photos so make one bridge table news_photos

**news_photos**

```
id
news_id
photo_id
```

Similarly One news may have multiple authors so make one bridge table news_authors

**news_authors**

```
id
news_id
author_id
```

Also One news may have multiple keywords so make one bridge table news_keywords

**news_keywords**

```
id
news_id
keyword_id
```

Comment: Perhaps the `featured` property should be in a `featured_news` table along with a `site_id`?  (so you can feature the article on multiple sites..?)

Comment: no idea but in most of the cases photos,author and keywords are multiple for the single news .. it is good practice to maintain seperte table . For example : later you may need to pull related news by matching tags

Comment: The `id` fields are not necessary in your bridge tables.

Comment: @thebjorn :yes , but some times if u use frameworks it become mandatory.

Comment: @timus2001 Why didn't you separate the keywords one per row?

Comment: @timus2001 In this case there is only one photo & one author but there will be multiple keywords. Doesn't having 8 tables broken down seem a bit excessive?

Comment: well i was thinking of future rather than present .. client might say i need mutiple photos and author. In that time you cant change structure. Please note that many to many relationship can be used for one to one relationship as well

Comment: @user3177012 no, not at all. It's standard best practice to group related information in separate tables. E.g. what would your scheme look like if you wanted to present the name of the author in addition to their email (would you repeat it for every row)?

Comment: @thebjorn Well in my case I have a sepperate Author table with `Email, Name, Avatar, Website_url, Facebook_link, Twitter_link, Bio`. So I use php to `select * from author where id == author` to display the author details at the bottom of every article, so additional details are added to that table

Comment: @user3177012 it's bad practice to use a changeable attribute as primary key.  People do change email addresses.. half the population will potentially change their last name..  You're not required to use an integer key, but it is very convenient.

Comment: @thebjorn Ok, I can see your point with that one - But I can't see that I'd need a `photos` table as the photo here is only relevant to the article, like a news article has a photo to represent it

Comment: @user3177012 Sure, but a photo has many properties that are not relevant to the article (photographer, license, size, thumbnail, etc.).  It makes more sense to keep all photo related data in its own table and just link to it with a foreign key from the news table (or use a many-to-many table as timus has shown).

Comment: @thebjorn Ok, but I'm still not convinced - I've updated my original question

Answer (score 0):

I reccomend you at least to move the Category and the Keywords in separate tables.

This will help you to write more effective SQL queries when you will have to search Articles by keywords or category.

On the other hand, you will have to write more code to do this, referring to data insert form, etc., but it will be better and more clear and absolutely better.

You should then:
Create a `Categories` table (`Id, Description`)
Create a `Keywords` table (`Article_Id, Keyword`)
Substitute your `Articles.Category` field with `Articles.Category_Id` and remove your `Articles.Keywords` field.

Comment: Thanks, but what's wrong with simply using `select * from articles where category == '$category'`?

Comment: @user3177012 then you'll need an index on the `category` column and if you're going to create an index why not get the full benefits of a seperate table..?

Comment: @user3177012 One of the matters is that the category description repeated in every article exposes you to typing errors, while having the categories repeated only one time in a different table is more "checkable"

Comment: @kiks73, you mean `category_name`? Even if the value is entered from the value in a dropdown menu?

Answer (score 0):

You duplicate much strings that describe category name. Much easier store integer value, instead category name each time.

Comment: Thanks,but the categories are going to be set up by the authors themselves, so it's not just a simple case of having `cat_1`, `cat_2`, `cat_3` - More a case of `author_1's cat_1`, `author_1's cat_2`, `author_2's cat_1`, etc, etc.

Answer (score 0):

How you choose to normalize largely depends on your business case, don't just normalise for the sake of it. That's why your design approach is crucial, starting off with an ERD (Top-Down approach) helps me in deciding how best to normalize.

Comment: Thanks. It's all just a bit confusing as to why a table that only has 12 columns needs to be split into 8 tables as suggested above. I've always used php to filter out information rather than trying to link several tables together